# String substitution in batch file name expansion

Tags: string, batch-file, replace

Is there a trick to doing string substitution on the variables like `"%~dp0"`?  I have been creating intermediate variables, then substituting, but was wondering if there was a way to cut out the intermediary?  For example, here I would like to replace `\` with `/` in the path

```
@echo off
setlocal
pushd "%~dp0"

:: doesn't work
echo."%~dp0:\=/"

:: with intermediate 'v'
set "v=%~dp0"
echo."%v:\=/%"

popd
```

I tried various combinations of quotes and `%`, but have just been taking shots in the dark.

Comment: there is no way around an intermediate variable.

Comment: `%0` isn't a environmental variable. And all functions that extract parts assume it's a filename.

Comment: @Stephan ok thanks! Ill quit trying then